# ArcGIS 3.x to 4.x Migration

Tags: geojson, arcgis-js-api

I was using [ArcGIS JS API](https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js) 3.10 and have a Github
 repository to display GeoJSON data on a map but now I have to upgrade to
 4.9 version I read 3.x to 4.x migration document published by ESRI and apply he changes like link location etc. but it’s not working anymore.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>ArcGIS GeoJSON Layer</title>
<!-- ArcGIS API for JavaScript CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/esri/css/main.css">
@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">*@
<!-- Web Framework CSS - Bootstrap (getbootstrap.com) and Bootstrap-map-js (github.com/esri/bootstrap-map-js) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//esri.github.io/bootstrap-map-js/src/css/bootstrapmap.css">
<style>
    html, body, #mapDiv {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/"></script>
<!-- ArcGIS API for JavaScript library references -->
@*<script src="//js.arcgis.com/3.10"></script>*@

<!-- Terraformer reference -->
<script src="/vendor/terraformer/terraformer.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/terraformer-arcgis-parser/terraformer-arcgis-parser.min.js"></script>

<script>
    require(["esri/Map",
        "/Scripts/Refine.js",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (Map, GeoJsonLayer, on, dom) {

            // Create map
            var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                basemap: "gray",
                center: [-122.5, 45.5],
                zoom: 5
            });

            map.on("load", function () {
                addGeoJsonLayer("http://113.197.55.251/api/punjab");
            });

            // Add the layer
            function addGeoJsonLayer(url) {
                // Create the layer
                var geoJsonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer({
                    url: url
                });
                // Zoom to layer
                geoJsonLayer.on("update-end", function (e) {
                    map.setExtent(e.target.extent.expand(1.2));
                });
                // Add to map
                map.add(geoJsonLayer);
            }
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ArcGIS 4.9 you have to use a [MapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) like below:

For the conversion between GeoJson and EsriJson, I suggest you the [arcgis-to-geojson-utils](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils) library

**Import the library in your html:**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils"></script>
```

**javascript:**

```
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/layers/support/Field",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (Map, MapView, Graphic, FeatureLayer, Field, on, dom) {

        // Create mapView and map
        var mapView = new MapView({
            container: mapDiv,
            map: new Map({
                basemap: "gray"
            }),
            center: [-122.5, 45.5],
            zoom: 5
        }).when(function(mapView) {
            makeRequest("http://113.197.55.251/api/punjab", function(response) {
                createLayerFromGeoJSON(response, mapView);
            });
        });

        // Request the geojson data using XmlHttpRequest
        function makeRequest(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function(error) {
              throw error;
            }
            xhr.send(); 
        };

        // Create the layer from the geojson data
        function createLayerFromGeoJSON(geojson, mapView) {

            // Convert geojson to esriJson using arcgis-to-geojson-utils library
            var esriJson = ArcgisToGeojsonUtils.geojsonToArcGIS(geojson);

            // Create an array of graphics from the esriJson
            var graphics = esriJson.map(function(feature, i) {
                return new Graphic({
                    geometry: {
                        type: "polygon",
                        rings: feature.geometry.rings
                    },
                    attributes: {
                        ObjectID: i,
                        Name: feature.attributes.Name
                    }
                 });
            });

            // Create a FeatureLayer from the graphics
            var layer = new FeatureLayer({
                title: "My feature layer",
                source: graphics, // autocast as an array of esri/Graphic
                geometryType: "polygon",
                fields: [
                    new Field({
                        name: "ObjectID",
                        alias: "ObjectID",
                        type: "oid"
                    }),
                    new Field({
                        name: "Name",
                        alias: "Name",
                        type: "string"
                    }),
                ], 
                objectIdField: "ObjectID", // This must be defined when creating a layer from Graphics
                renderer: {
                    type: "simple",  // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
                    symbol: {
                        type: "simple-fill",  // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
                        color: {r: 200, g: 200, b: 200, a: 0.5},
                        outline: {  // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                            width: 0.5,
                            color: "black"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            mapView.map.add(layer);
            return layer;
        };

    });
```

Comment: i use the code you provide but still no luck one more thing the link i have provided is GeoJson (polygon) and you are creating point, secondly  i have gone through Esri documentation and sample code for goejson the library i linked with my question i need that library to be updated according to 4.9 version.
this library is created to convert geojson data to arcjson and display it on map please try to upgrade the library according to 4.9 version.
https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js/blob/master/src/geojsonlayer.js

Comment: Upgrading this library would be the task of the author of the library. I have modified my answer using another library that will convert your `geoJson` to `esriJson`. Then we use the esriJson to create `Graphics` and a `FeatureLayer` using the v4.9 API

Comment: have you tested it because its not working on my side.
dojo.js:24 Error: multipleDefine
    at r (dojo.js:5)
    at nb (dojo.js:21)
    at dojo.js:22
    at c (dojo.js:4)
    at Oa (dojo.js:22)
    at p (dojo.js:21)
    at J (dojo.js:21)
    at c (dojo.js:4)
    at dojo.js:11
    at E (dojo.js:19)

Comment: it says 
arcgis4.9.js:77 Error: multipleDefine
and
Uncaught TypeError: Map is not a constructor

Comment: Okay i was setting your library on top then ArcGIS api so i get problem so now that problem is solved but then i got this 

OPTIONS https://113.197.55.251/api/punjab net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: i have checked it, its not down you can try it as well.

Comment: i have already .. and then 

Index:112 Uncaught ReferenceError: geojsonToArcGIS is not defined
    at createLayerFromGeoJSON (Index:112)
    at Index:88
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (Index:99)

Comment: ok move to next level now i got this 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Index:120
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createLayerFromGeoJSON (Index:115)
    at Index:88
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (Index:99)

Comment: as i have update with your provided code i got this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at createLayerFromGeoJSON (Index:114)
    at Index:87
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (Index:98)

Comment: when i console the esriJson its only have attributes and Geometry so why are you pointing features out of it and then map i dont get it please take a closer look.

Comment: var graphics = esriJson.features.map(function(feature, i) i am geting error at this line

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at createLayerFromGeoJSON (Index:114) at Index:87 at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (Index:98)

Comment: well i have CORS enable on my side

Comment: i am getting tuns of error in dojo please try it on your side

Comment: what if i provide you geojson file or you test it on some sample geojson

Comment: [esri.core.Accessor] Accessor#set Invalid property value, value needs to be one of 'esri.geometry.Extent', 'esri.geometry.Multipoint', 'esri.geometry.Point', 'esri.geometry.Polyline', 'esri.geometry.Polygon', 'esri.geometry.Mesh', or a plain object that can autocast (having .type = 'extent', 'multipoint', 'point', 'polyline', 'polygon', 'mesh'

Comment: -------------
[esri.layers.FeatureLayer] #load() Failed to load layer (title: 'null', id: '1672fbf613d-layer-0') e {name: "feature-layer:missing-property", message: "geometryType not set and couldn't be inferred from the provided features", details: undefined}
-------------
[esri.views.LayerViewFactory] Failed to create view for layer 'null, id:1672fbf613d-layer-0' of type 'feature'.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGis Js 4.x version you have to also declare a view constructor (MapView for 2D or SceneView for 3D). Here is a guide on how to set up 2D view: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-mapview/index.html

Another way to add Json file is to convert your existing your json file to an esri json format, like in this guide: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=layers-featurelayer-collection.

Since I don't know your json file attributes I can't really provide a working sample, but its really simple.

Comment: thank you that you took the time to help me out. i have provide the link where from i am getting geojson data http://113.197.55.251/api/punjab its polygon but the challenge is to upgrade that library https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js/blob/master/src/geojsonlayer.js according to arcgis api 4.9 version.